# Ranges of all columns of all csv files in R

Tags: r

I have 300 csv files containing same data sets, I want to calculate minimum and maximum values (ranges) of all columns in all csv files and want to create final table with minimum and maximum values of all these csv files and all columns. I am using the following function by could not figure out how to work in the loop and develop final table.

```
kk <- Map(function(x) cbind(x,min=min(var[,x]),
                            max=max(var[,x])), as.list(names(var)))
data.frame(do.call(rbind,kk))
```

Comment: When you say 'same data sets', do you mean same number of columns and rows but different cell values?

Comment: I have the same variables for columns and rows in all CSV files having different values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building a list of data frames carrying min and max of each column across all datasets:

```
# GET LIST OF CSV FILES
csv_files <- list.files(pattern=".csv")

df_list <- lapply(csv_files, function(f) {
    df <- read.csv(f)
    # BUILD LIST OF MIN AND MAX ACROSS ALL COLUMNS
    agg_list <- lapply(df, function(col) c(min(col), max(col)))
    # BIND AGGREGATES INTO A DATA FRAME
    min_max_df <- do.call(data.frame, agg_list)

    # RETURN UPDATE DF WITH TWO NEW COLUMNS
    transform(min_max_df, file_name = f, aggregate=c("min", "max"))
})

# CONCATENATE ALL DFs
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

Comment: I am sorry, Actually, I am quite new with R... If you elaborate your code that will be very great for me because I am having error with this.Error: unexpected symbol in:
"agg_list <- lapply("df", function(col) c(min(col), max(col))
min_max_df"

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ... it works perfectly this time ..... Thank you.